# PCI Scan Fail on SSLv3 Supported port tcp/38933

Tags: security, pci

I got a PCI Scan Fail today on SSLv3 Supported port tcp/38933, tcp/40549 and tcp/41049. Any suggestions on what should I do?

Comment: `Any suggestions on what should I do?` - Honestly, hire someone that knows what this means and what to do about it. You'll learn something in the process.

Answer (score 1):

[Disable SSLv3](http://disablessl3.com/). It's cryptographically broken.

And find out what those services are that are running on those odd, high-numbered ports. And shut them down.